# inhibit-read-only affects all buffers when *Backtrace* buffer is open

Tags: debugging

I use `buffer-read-only` as a safety measure for anything that is important.  Recently, I have been debugging functions that use `inhibit-read-only` and I leave the `*Backtrace*` open to go about my business and go back to the `*Backtrace*` buffer from time to time.  This unfortunately disables `read-only` in all open buffers.

**Q**:  How can I leave the `*Backtrace*` buffer open and still keep all other buffers just the way they were (i.e., read-only)?

```
(let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (error "stop"))
```

**EDIT**:  Here is the link to the bug report:  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26947

Comment: Sounds like a bug, to me. Please consider `M-x report-emacs-bug` with a recipe to repro.